# Can I test if a tag is closed like this <hello/> (XML) with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

Well, I'm doing a transformation XML to JSON with XSLT.

My client wants the following:

- When you get a tag `<hello/>`, you transform this field in JSON as null.
- When you get a tag `<hello></hello>`, a transform this field in JSON as "" (empty string).

So how can I test if a tag is `<hello/>` or `<hello></hello>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases an XSLT processor just uses an XML parser to  parse the XML input into some XDM tree and that way there is no difference  or distinction between `<foo/>` or `<foo></foo>`.

Answer (score 1):

**No,** you cannot detect the difference between those two forms of empty elements in XSLT.

There is no semantic difference between `<hello/>` and `<hello></hello>`, and any consuming software that differentiates the two forms is broken and should be fixed, not catered to.

Having said that, some XML serialization modules may support an option that provides control to the user over which form to use for empty elements.  Feel uneasy as you look up how in the software's documentation.  Then thoroughly wash your hands.